# What is this plant growing out of a building?

Tags: identification

What is this flowering plant growing out of a wall? How is this possible at all?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't see the flowers completely clearly, the pic doesn't magnify well, but most likely it's Cymbalaria muralis; it has plenty of common names, the one used most often in the UK being ivy-leaved toadflax. It directs its seed pods at any crevice or crack where it might be able to grow, and is common on old walls, cracks between paving, growing in small amounts of soil that have blown in and are present in such places, although it will also grow in borders or lawns if it's not weeded out. https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/57492/Cymbalaria-muralis/Details

Comment: It is truly the same plant on my photo and your link, everything matches: unusual white - light burgundy flower, leaf shape. That is the right plant! Very unusual plant. And another difficult latin name. :)

Comment: There are worse names! But everyone I know just calls this Toadflax...which is much easier. It only really matters if you actually  want to buy some.

Comment: In US we call it "Kenilworth ivy". Worth mentioning also, regarding its Latin name, the word "muralis" pertains to a wall.

Comment: 'muralis' - 'of walls' is the meaning attributed in my Plant Names Book...

Comment: Yes, Kenilworth ivy!  Thanks Lorel!  Plants can grow in cracks so easily if there is regular moisture and some decomposition of the wall and filled with dirt or dust.  Big conifer trees can take hold in the tiles of a roof to become a huge part of a monastery.  Plants break boulders apart by growing in the cracks.  Gosh, thanks, Lorel!  I would have gone nuts trying to remember Kenilworth Ivy.  Always part of the plant starts to tuck in hanging baskets and pots.

Comment: @stormy no need to have gone nuts - the link I supplied mentions Kenilworth Ivy as one of its names anyway!

Comment: I grins, did not go nuts...!  I just knew this plant like an old auntie, very familiar and didn't go to your link right away.  Lorel...said the name and hey, it is nice to remember again, an old friend.  It doesn't take long when one isn't shopping and planting plants all day long...to forget names!  Great little plant for pots otherwise it can get carried away in the landscape.  Pretty thing!

Comment: @stormy  I forget names even still buying and planting - those times when the client  says what's this plant, and you know what it is, you've known for years, but you stand there like a temporarily disabled robot because the name refuses to present itself. Infuriating, especially as it might pop into my head 10 minutes later, or a random time a week later... its age related,that,I'm afraid...